# cross-domain iframe contentWindow

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

I would like to exchange messages via postMessage with an iframe on my page that is pointing to a page on a different domain (which I own).

Just by looking at the demo http://html5demos.com/postmessage2 and reading a bit on the web, I understood that I have to call postMessage on the contentWindow of the iframe. i.e.

```
var iframe=document.getElementById('myframe');
var win=iframe.contentWindow;

//just send the message
win.postMessage('Help!',mydomain);
```

Now, the point is that, when I try to get the contentWindow, I get "DOM Exception" so I cannot send any message to the iframe.

I am wondering if I need to set up something on the page that is displayed within the iframe to accept this cross-domain communication... but I have to say that I am completely clueless...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iframe cross domain messaging with jQuery postMessage plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10931158/iframe-cross-domain-messaging-with-jquery-postmessage-plugin)